# Uncaught OAuthException Error with Facebook PHP api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using php SDK of FB (version 3.2.0) for my application for `FB Login` and  when i tried to get the userid using 
 `facebook->getUser()`  methode , its returns  the user id , but when i triedto get the user data using  `facebook->api('/me')` methode it returns the error

> Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query
>   information about the current user

Both are working if am not logged into FB and getting logged through the FB login link .
If am logged into FB and tried to get the user data , it always result in the error

Please help me

Comment: _“I am using php SDK of FB (version 3.2.0)”_ – current version is __v.3.2.2__, and it contains a bug fix that addresses issues arising from the recent change (code can be exchanged for access token only once) – so please go update it.

Comment: Thanks CBore .... its working now .. I hope that might be my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Check for the user_id first and if it's null reauthorize the user as shown in the following example:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/